# call a method after the object is released?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, release

i was reading this code, where `setRegions` is called after `RootViewController` is released : i find it a bit strange : does it mean `RootViewController` is still accessible, even if it was released and `self.navigationController` "owns" it ?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    // Create the navigation and view controllers
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    self.navigationController = aNavigationController;
    [aNavigationController release];
    [rootViewController release];

    [rootViewController setRegions:[Region knownRegions]];

    // Configure and display the window
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is bad code.

An object should retain another object for as long as it cares about it.  And in this case that rule is broken.  The `rootViewController` is released, and then as you note, a method is called on it.  This can be dangerous.

In this case, it works.  This is because `rootViewController` is passed to another object, which retains it.  So when we release it, it still has a positive retain count and is not deallocated.  So our reference to it still works, and methods called on it work fine.

But lets say some implementation changed and `initWithRootViewController:` now no longer retained it's argument for some reason (an assumption you can't really make all the time).  Suddenly this all crashes because `rootViewController` gets deallocated.

To fix this funk, you just need to move `[rootViewController release];` to after the last useful reference of that object in this function.  Your code then becomes more robust and more correct.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    // Create the navigation and view controllers
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [rootViewController setRegions:[Region knownRegions]];
    UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    self.navigationController = aNavigationController;

    // Release temporary objects since we've now sent them to other other objects
    // which may or may not retain them (we don't really care which here)
    [aNavigationController release];
    [rootViewController release];

    // Configure and display the window
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

---

Last thing to note: `release` and `dealloc` are very different things.  `release` does not necessarily destroy objects.  It simply decrements the `retain` count by one.  And if that `retain` count ever gets to zero, *only then* is the object is deallocated.  So this code works because a `release` happens but without triggering a `dealloc`.

Answer (score 1):

The above is very dangerous code. It might happen to work, but it's just getting lucky. You should never access a variable after you have released it. In fact, it is best practice to immediately set variables to `nil` after releasing them if they don't immediately go out of scope. Some people only do this in Release mode, and so create a macro like:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define RELEASE(x) [x release];
#else
#define RELEASE(x) [x release]; x = nil;
#endif
```

The reason for this is to help catch bugs in debug mode (by having a crash rather than just a silent `nil` pointer), while being a bit safer in release mode.

But in any case, you should never access a variable after you've released it.

Answer (score 1):

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

(objectA created, retain count is 1, rootViewController points to it)

```
UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
```

(objectB created, retain count is 1, aNavigationController points to it)
(objectA retain count is 2 now, both rootViewController and some property in self.aNavigationController point to it)

```
self.navigationController = aNavigationController;
```

(objectB retain count is 2 now, both aNavigationController and self.navigationController point to it; assuming self.navigationController is a retain property)

```
[aNavigationController release];
```

(objectB retain count is 1 now, however, both aNavigationController and self.navigationController point to it)

```
[rootViewController release];
```

(objectA retain count is 1 now, however, both rootViewController and some property in self.aNavigationController point to it)

```
[rootViewController setRegions:[Region knownRegions]];
```

(use rootViewController to access objectA)
(This is not good)

Following is my recommended way:

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
[rootViewController setRegions:[Region knownRegions]];

UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController] autorelease];
self.navigationController = aNavigationController;
```